# Generate a Random Number and Return it

Tags: python-3.x, random

I've searched for an answer through stack but all answers are too complicated for me to understand (I have just started learning about python programming). All I want to do is generate a random number, say between 20 and 30, and then name that random number (so if the random number is 25 then have shotDistance = 25). Below is the code I have at the moment for mt random number but I keep getting errors such as "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'method'" or "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'srt'". Because after returning the randomNumber I have it in a calculation (totalDistanceRemaining = totalDistanceRemaining - shotDistance) and that's where it says the error.

```
def calculateDriverShot ():
import random
random.randint(24, 36)
shotDistance = random.randint
return shotDistance
```

Below is the code with the calculation in which I need the random number returned under the name shotDistance.

```
        elif clubSelection == 'd':
        calculateDriverShot ()
        shotDistance = calculateDriverShot()
        hitsNumber = hitsNumber + 1
        totalDistanceRemaining = totalDistanceRemaining - shotDistance
        print("Your shot went " + str(shotDistance) + "m. You are " + str(totalDistanceRemaining) + " from the hole, after " + str(hitsNumber) + " shot/s.")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you need a very basic tutorial, starting with what a function is, how to call it and assign the return value. Given your current attempt and the statement that "all answers are too complicated for me to understand", I would expect that any answer given here would have the same problem. I would suggest returning to SO after reading some tutorials to the point that you can understand the other answers you found.

Comment: I know what a function is , how to call it and assign the return value I've done it before. However I'm having trouble with the random number generator.

Comment: Forgive me for saying so, but your code shows otherwise. The random number generator is just a function. You are definitely not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your function whitespace is wrong, and you should never import a module inside of the function. Fix this to prevent errors in the future. Next, in the `calculateShotDistance` function, you are calling randint, but you are making `shotDistance` a different number altogether by calling randint again, without any parameters (This is giving an error, as you are asking it to print a class object.). Then again, you do not need `shotdistance` in the function. Here is the shortened code, and you can fix the parts you need.

```
from random import *

def calculateDriverShot()
    return randint(20, 30)

shotDistance = calculateDriverShot()
```

I would also recommend that you look through some tutorials on functions and modules (as in comments on question). This is a good link to start with: http://rwet.decontextualize.com/book/functions/